# How can I target the same player that was previously targeted randomly?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am making a Minecraft commands map and need to give a random player two effects and one item.

I understand that each effect/item needs to be given in a separate command. The problem is, `@r` targets a random player each time, but I need the effects and items to be given to the *same* randomly targeted player.

How can I give these effects/items to the same player?

Answer (score 2):

1. Tag the random player.

   ```
   /tag @r add RandomSelection
   ```

   Note, your tag name should not contain spaces!
2. Give them the effects and item by targeting the player with the tag.

   ```
   /effect @a[tag=RandomSelection] fire_resistance
   /give @a[tag=RandomSelection] stone
   ```
3. Remove the tag.

   ```
   /tag @a[tag=RandomSelection] remove RandomSelection
   ```